# Regex to match phone number 5ABXXYYZZ

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to match 9 digits phone numbers.

I have this pattern  `5ABXXYYZZ` that I want to match.

*What I tried*

I have this regex that matches two repetitions only `5ABCDYYZZ`

```
S_P_2 = 541982277
S_P_2_pattern = re.sub(r"(?!.*(\d)\1(\d)\2(\d)\3).{4}\d(\d)\4(\d)\5", "Special", str(S_P_2))
print(S_P_2_pattern)
```

*What I want to achieve*

I would like to update it to match three repetitions `5ABXXYYZZ` sample `541882277`

Comment: Can you confirm that 'X!=Z'?

Comment: confirmed yes they can't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^5\d\d(?:(\d)\1(?!.*\1)){3}$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/x5Zvnj/1)

- `^5\d\d` - Start-line anchor and literal 5 before two random digits;
- `(?:(\d)\1(?!.*\1)){3}` - Non-capture group matched three times with nested capture group followed by itself directly but (due to negative lookahead) again after 0+ chars;
- `$` - End-line anchor.